# Problem with MaTeX PlotLabel

Tags: plotting, labeling, matex

I'm trying to label a plot as follows:

```
Plot[{Re[kai4] /. sol, Im[kai4] /. sol}, {z, 0, 2}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> BlackFrame, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLabel -> "Numerical Solution" MaTeX@"\chi_4", 
 PlotStyle -> {{Black}, {Black, Dashed}},
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman"},
 FrameLabel -> MaTeX@{"x_3", "\chi_4"}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[MaTeX@{"Re", "Im"}, Below]]
```

and I have the problem that the MaTeX part of PlotLabel appears at the start. How do I fix this? I want it to appear in the order I typed it.

[image]

Comment: try `PlotLabel  -> Row[{ "Numerical Solution", MaTeX@"\chi_4" }]`?

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you. Submit as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Or just `MaTeX["\\text{Numerical Solution $\\chi_4$}"]`

Comment: You should know that the code you wrote is invalid (and only works because an accident and Mathematica's sloppiness about error reporting). `"\chi"` is not valid. You must write `"\\chi"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
PlotLabel -> Row[{"Numerical Solution", MaTeX@"\\chi_4" }]
```

to prevent re-ordering of the two expressions in the label.